# Is it possible to create one Firebase Storage trigger and apply it on all buckets?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have a Firebase Project that has many buckets

I want to implement a trigger `onFinalize()` and `onDelete()`, this trigger will have the same logic for all buckets in the storage

Can't I use this trigger on all buckets? or do I need to create a new specific trigger for each bucket separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to apply a single deployed trigger to multiple buckets.  Each bucket must have its own trigger deployed (but you are of course free to share the same code for each one).  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#trigger-function-on-storage-changes):

> Use functions.storage to create a function that handles Cloud Storage
> events. Depending on whether you want to scope your function to a
> specific Cloud Storage bucket or use the default bucket, use one of
> the following:
>
> - functions.storage.object() to listen for object changes on the default Cloud Storage bucket.
> - functions.storage.bucket('bucketName').object() to listen for object changes on a specific bucket.